"Vector Character" in Whitehead's Process and Reality
In Process and Reality, Alfred North Whitehead discusses the concept of "prehensions" and describes them as having a "vector character." Coming from a physics background, I typically associate vectors with one-dimensional arrays having magnitude and direction. However, Whitehead seems to use the term in a more philosophical or abstract sense.
Can someone explain what Whitehead means by "vector character" in this context? How should I understand "prehensions" and their relationship to the external world, emotion, purpose, and valuation?
Any insight into how Whitehead’s use of "vector" relates to its more common mathematical or physical definition would be helpful as well. Thanks!

Could you add an extended quote? Whitehead was an accomplished mathematician, so my guess is that he meant prehensions involve both a direction and a distance. In fact, I have a very vague memory of reading a passage like that and deciding that's what he meant, but it's a memory from decades ago, so not very reliable.

Before Hamilton, "vector" had the meaning of that which carries or conveys, a vehicle of relating.

"Whitehead says:"Feelings are ‘vectors’; for they feel what is there and transform it into what is here" (PR 133). This notion of the vector character of prehensions is basic to his attempt to describe the world as a multiplicity of actual things which are genuinely related. For the notion that prehensions are vectors is a rejection... that an actual entity’s location can be described without reference to other actualities" Griffin.

@Conifold, ah, that's right. It is still used that way in medicine. A disease has a "vector".

most people think of vectors as being 2 dinesional arrows on a cartesian plane, it's kind of weird that you imagine them as 1-d arrays. also i'm not sure how that 1-d array of yours can contain information about both magnitude and direction

@DennisKozevnikoff That's a superficial mathematical reading. When you take linear algebra, you learn to think of vectors as linear combinations in the abstract. Thus while an ai+bj construction introduces the topic, vectors are any arbitrary [a,b,c,d,...] where an n-dimension tuple extends the notion. In industry, LLMs and the like are built on vector databses like with transformer models.

@DennisKozevnikoff a vector could be an arrow in 3d space as well as 2d, right? In linear algebra, we expand this into a vector in a n-dimensional (or infinite-dimensional) vector space. For instance, we can represent random processes as markov chains with a stochastic transition matrix. If you want to know what will happen with a given initial starting state after n steps of the process, you can start with a probability vector with p=1 in one dimension, and then multiply by the matrix n times.

so in the 2-dimensional case, you have 2-element arrays [a, b] and magnitude is sqrt(a^2 + b^2), direction is atan2(b, a), right. In the n dimensional case, the magnitude is still the root of the sum of squares, and the direction is usually written as a vector of length 1 (since there's many more angles to specify. Though we can write the angles, like this)

The full paragraph from page 19 of Process and Reality:

Each actual entity is analysable in an indefinite number of ways. In
some modes of analysis the component elements are more abstract than
in other modes of analysis. The analysis of an actual entity into 'pre
hensions' is that mode of analysis which exhibits the most concrete ele
ments in the nature of actual entities. This mode of analysis will be termed
the 'division' of the actual entity in question. Each actual entity is 'divis
ible' in an indefinite number of ways, and each way of 'division' yields its
definite quota of prehensions. A prehension reproduces in itself the general
characteristics of an actual entity : it is referent to an external world, and
in this sense will be said to have a 'vector character'; it involves emotion,
and purpose, and valuation, and causation. In fact, any characteristic of
an actual entity is reproduced [29] in a prehension. It might have been a
complete actuality; but, by reason of a certain incomplete partiality, a pre
hension is only a subordinate element in an actual entity. A reference to
the complete actuality is required to give the reason why such a prehension
is what it is in respect to its subjective form. This subjective form is
determined by the subjective aim at further integration, so as to obtain
the 'satisfaction' of the completed subject. In other words, final causation
and atomism are interconnected philosophical principles.

He also says:

Feelings are 'vectors'; for they feel what is there and transform it into what is here.


and remember that in physics 'vector' means definite transmission from elsewhere

So we can surmise that what he means by saying prehension has a vector character, is that prehension refers to an external world, and is therefore an "arrow" from the external world to an internal world. A transmission from the external world to the internal world.
To explain the mathematical reason for this, if you have points A and B, then B - A is the vector pointing from A to B. An arrow between two places can thus be represented with a vector.

+1 Nice. The OP should be aware https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=vector shows "1704, from Latin vector "one who carries or conveys, carrier" (also "one who rides"), agent noun from past-participle stem of vehere "carry, convey" (from PIE root *wegh- "to go, move, transport in a vehicle")
